# I am trying to change date which is in string format to date format in python

Tags: python, selenium

I have written the code as below:

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime_str = '19/09/2021'

datetime_object = datetime.strptime(datetime_str, '%d/%m/%Y').date()

print(type(datetime_object))
print(datetime_object)
```

I am getting the output as below:

```
(venv) D:\pythonProject\practice>py test1.py
<class 'datetime.date'>
2021-09-19
```

Here the date format is changing to 2021-09-19

I need the same format as '19/09/2021' in date type

I tried to change the format as below:

```
newformat = datetime_object.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
print(newformat)
print(type(newformat))
```

But newformat is in string type. Could you please help me out to resolve this issue?

Comment: the internal way a datetime object stores the date does not matter to you. `strftime` returns a string representation of a datetime object according to the formatting you give it which is why `newformat` is a string

Answer (score 0):

This line will do:

```
print(datetime_object.strftime("%d/%m/%Y "))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `print(datetime_object)` actually calls the `datetime.datetime.__str__()` function. It is defined in the datetime.datetime class ([source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/366dc3a1354078e38808b9c16276e97cca5b8aaf/Lib/datetime.py#L1943)). It returns isoformat by default.

If you want to modify the `print(datetime_object)`, You can use inheritance to create a new class derived from the class of interest, and then overriding the `__str__` method. Then you define your datetime_object using your new class.

```
class mydatetime(datetime):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
mydatetime_object = mydatetime.strptime(datetime_str, '%d/%m/%Y')
print(type(mydatetime_object))
print(mydatetime_object)
```

You can expect to get:

```
<class '__main__.mydatetime'>
19/09/2021
```

The funciton `strftime()` converts the datetime.datetime object into a string, so you get a string instead of a datetime.datetime object.